# How to print out list items from a list of strings that contain any item of another list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of words like:

```
lst = [
    "white", 
    "green",
    "blue", 
    "cat", 
    "dog"
    ]
```

And I also have tokenized text like:

```
tokenized_text = ["This is a sentence.", "This is another sentence.", "This sentence contains a word from the list: cat.", "Finally, this is the last sentence."]
```

I'd like to print out all the list items from the `tokenized_text` list that contain either of the words from `lst`.

Based on the example above, the expected output should be: `['This sentence contains a word from the list: cat.']`

I'm new to Python and already tried a few things, but the only thing that I was able to achieve is to check whether or not the text contains any of the words in the list.

EDIT: I changed the list name to `lst` from `list`.

Comment: A list comprehension works: `[txt for txt in tokenized_text if any(word in txt for word in lst)]` (note I changed `list` to `lst` since `list` is a built-in function and you should not use it as a variable name). But this may not help you. If you [edit] and add your code, we can show you where you went wrong.

Comment: Yes, that does exactly what I wanted to do! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want list comprehension

```py
for word in lst:
  for token in tokenized_text:
    if word in token:
      print(token)
```